# Problems with Broadband modem in Lenovo Thinkpad T460p

Tags: thinkpad, mobile-broadband

I have a lenovo T460p laptop. It has a mobile broadband modem, which is listed with lsusb like this:

```
001 Device 002: ID 12d1:15c1 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

I can connect to the internet with it. But sometimes the connection is dropped, and I cannot reconnect (until I restart the laptop). I tried this:

```
sudo mmcli -m 0 --simple-connect="pin=XXXX,apn=internet"
```

and I get this:

```
error: couldn't connect the modem: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.MobileEquipment.Unknown: No cause information available'
```

What could this or how can I debug this further?

**Update:** I am connecting using the network-manager in gnome.

Comment: How are you connecting? Are you using the included software of the modem or only the network manager?

Comment: @GTRONICK I updated my answer

Comment: check this answer: [Broadband modem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/649324/ubuntu14-04-une-4g-lte-mobile-modem-not-connecting/649536#649536)

Comment: @GTRONICK The suggestion is to use Modem Manager GUI. As far as I can see, one can not start a connection using that tool. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: The solution was to use that tool. I have used it as well, and have worked fine. I mean, I'm suggesting to you, to use that tool, or at least test it and see if it works in your case. Regards

Comment: @GTRONICK I understand, and I am trying my best to test it. I searched every corner of the modem-manager-gui, but I simple cannot find the button to establish the connection ...